# get value from one view & set it on element in another view in yii

Tags: variables, yii, view

I have a view file called "user" .There it has a select tag called 'uid'.I will select a user id from the select tag and click on 'add' button.When I click 'add' button it will redirect to another view called 'projects' .  There I have a select tag called 'userID' I want to set the value of this option to  'uid' which I have selected in 'user' view. How can I do this?

I don't want to pass the variable in url

Answer (score 1):

I have never worked on PHP but you can try one of the following options:

1. You can pass that value in URL and access it on project view.

   eg: /project/uid=1001
2. Use can store on client side using Local Storage or Session Storage.
   http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideHtml5Storage.html

You can also use Route Parameters:

```
Use following link: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url
```

Hope this might